# didReceiveLocalNotification not active in iOS6

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Recently I am trying to create an alarm clock, and when I use UILocalNotification, the problem occur. It will show a banner when the app is in background, but when the app is active, even thought I have used didReceiveLocalNotification, there is no reaction at all. 
Why?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

UIApplicationState state = application.applicationState;

if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    NSLog(@"RingRingRing~~~~~");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Remind" message:notification.alertBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Sure" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Neither Remote or local notifications does not wakeup the application in iOS. it takes a user's action on the notification to launch the app.

Comment: sorry..but i can not get your point..can you explain it with more detail? thx

Comment: Is that means that I have to write a didReceiveLocalNotification: in the AppDelegate.m ?

Comment: The didReceiveLocalNotification is being called when your app is active - in that case, this call will replace the actual notification.
When your app is not active, you will get the information that it has been launched due to the user's pushing the button, only if the user does that.